# Fragments Within Fragment Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I'm building an application that requires Tabs, which are now deprecated. The dev guide says to use Fragments to replace the tabs instead. However, my application needs to have fragments within each tab, which means fragments inside fragments, which isn't allowed. Does anyone know of a possible work around for this?

Answer (score 3):

While the action bar support for tabs is designed to make it easy for the contents of a tab to be a fragment, that is not strictly required. You could use `ViewFlipper`, repeated calls to `setContentView()`, or something to arrange to change other stuff when the action bar tab is selected.

Prior to the native action bar (Android 1.x/2.x), either stick with classic tabs, or use something like [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to get an action bar and tabs.

Comment: Would using a ViewFlipper be more efficient than calling setContentView each time the tab changes? Is it the other way around or is the difference negligible?

Comment: @TJThind: If you inflate the layouts yourself and supply them to `setContentView()`, instead of giving `setContentView()` the layout ID, `setContentView()` and `ViewFlipper` will be equivalent speed-wise and memory-wise. Calling `setContentView()` the way you normally do, with a resource ID, would be slower (inflates every time, plus you have to wire up your event listeners every time) but tie up less heap (widgets removed by the next `setContentView()` call could be garbage collected, if done properly).

Answer (score 1):

I fake tabs by having a "tabs" fragment across the top that contains multiple toggle buttons. Below that I have a merge view containing a separate fragment for each tab.
I respond to taps on a toggle button by toggling the other buttons "off", showing the fragment for that "tab", and hiding the others.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by merge view?

Comment: Is it possible you could show me some example code, specifically an xml layout file? I'm having a hard-time grasping how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

its little late , but yes you can :) here's an [example](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/)
but for fragment inside fragment inside tab isn't an android native way, you have to start a   new fragmentActivity if you want to show detail of fragment. you can but is not an android way !